# psql - loop variable of loop over rows must be a record or row variable or list of scalar variables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, for-loop, psql

Here is my simple anonymous code block:

```
do $$
  declare foo varchar(50) := '';
  begin
    for a in
      select a from (values('foo'), ('bar'), ('fooBar')) s(a)
    loop
      foo := a;
      print foo;
    end loop;
  end;
$$;
```

When I run it:

```
psql -f test.sql
```

I get this error:

```
psql:test.sql:11: ERROR:  loop variable of loop over rows must be a record or row variable or list of scalar variables
LINE 4:     for a in
            ^
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Solved it myself, meh. Needed to declare `arow record`.

```
do $$
  declare
    arow record;
    foo varchar(50);
  begin
    for arow in
      select a from (values('foo'), ('bar'), ('fooBar')) s(a)
    loop
      foo := arow.a;
      RAISE NOTICE 'Calling cs_create_job(%)', foo;
    end loop;
  end;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks saved my day.
Can you just remove that s(a), it confused me for a while :(

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  loop variable of loop over rows must be a record variable or list of scalar variables

When I tried to iterate table's rows with a [FOR statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
  FOR row IN SELECT * FROM person LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', row;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

So, I declared `row` local variable as shown below, then the error was solved:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  row RECORD; -- Here
BEGIN
  FOR row IN SELECT * FROM person LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', row;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

In addition, a [FOREACH statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) must need a declared local variable as shown below, otherwise there is [the error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64046/error-loop-variable-of-foreach-must-be-a-known-variable-or-list-of-variables#335496):

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  temp VARCHAR; -- Here
BEGIN
  FOREACH temp SLICE 0 IN ARRAY ARRAY['a','b','c'] LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', temp;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Answer (score -1):

How to retrieve the error
Loop variable of loop over rows must be a record variable or list of scalar variables
Line : For c_ rec IN (select datasourcenm,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).